Magento246:Product is still visilble for non-logged in customers after setting category permission to logged in user only?
I created a test category called Test added a test product and set category permission to Logged in user only.

so the category and product shouldn't be visible to non-logged-in customers. but when I use Search product it shows in Search Results.

and this is my category permission configuration.

Any Idea, Thanks.

I could not figure out why it was behaving this way, but created an alternate solution to fix this issue.

Pyaray/CatalogPermission/etc/frontend/events.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
        <observer name="magento_catalogpermissions_"
                  instance="Pyaray\CatalogPermission\Observer\ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>


Pyaray\CatalogPermission\Observer\ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver

<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pyaray\CatalogPermission\Observer;

use Magento\CatalogPermissions\Model\PermissionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory as CustomerSessionFactory;
use Magento\CatalogPermissions\Model\ResourceModel\Permission\CollectionFactory as PermissionCollectionFactory;

class ApplyProductPermissionOnCollectionAfterLoadObserver implements  ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    private ProductRepository $productRepository;
    /**
     * @var CustomerSessionFactory
     */
    private CustomerSessionFactory $customerSessionFactory;
    /**
     * @var PermissionCollectionFactory
     */
    private PermissionCollectionFactory $permissionCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     * @param CustomerSessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
     * @param PermissionCollectionFactory $permissionCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
        CustomerSessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
        PermissionCollectionFactory $permissionCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        $this->permissionCollectionFactory = $permissionCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $isAllowed = false;
        $customerSession = $this->customerSessionFactory->create();
        if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $items = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->getItems();
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $product = $this->productRepository->getById($item->getEntityId());
                $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
                foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
                    $permission = $this->permissionCollectionFactory->create();
                    $permissions = $permission->addFieldToFilter('category_id', ['eq'=>$categoryId])
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id',['eq'=>0])->getData();
                    if ($permissions) {
                        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
                            if ($permission['grant_catalog_category_view'] == -1) {
                                $isAllowed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($isAllowed == false)
                {
                    $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

